# GridLayout: setMinimumWidth to oblige to Horizontal Constraints?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

Related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421353/gridlayout-spitting-out-inconsistent-constraint-debug-level-logs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997670/gridlayout-vertical-horizontal-constraints-are-inconsistent). But they do not answer my question.

I'm trying to add the buttons dynamically at runtime, so there is minimal design stage xml. All the buttons are created at runtime. All works fine till four buttons are added to a single line. It goes awry when a fifth button is added to the GridLayout.

I'm trying to affect the constraints to avoid the below error I get, when I add the fifth button:-

```
D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=231, x2-x1>=231, x3-x2>=231, x4-x3>=231, x5-x4>=231, x5-x0<=1080 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x5-x0<=1080.
```

There are five buttons in my GridLayout trying to squeeze themselves but they do not fit in `1080dp`, as `231dp*5=1155`.
 1. Where is the `231dp` coming from?
Output from the logs show that the `Button.getMinimumWidth()` was `231dp` (Scroll to the right to see the last parameter):-

```
D/CommandCenter: Btn <0> details:X<0.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<0> || MinW<231>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <1> details:X<270.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<270> || MinW<231>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <2> details:X<540.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<540> || MinW<231>
I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Debugger
D/CommandCenter: Btn <3> details:X<810.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<810> || MinW<231>
```

[image]
 2. Change the minimum width from `231dp` to `216dp` as below:

```
//btnContainer --> GridLayout Object
//btn          --> Button Object
//BTN_COLS     --> Number of Buttons in one row
btn.setMinimumWidth(btnContainer.getWidth()/BTN_COLS);
```

3. Check if the minimum width was set properly(Scroll to the right, the param MinW in log line):

```
D/CommandCenter: Btn <0> details:X<0.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<0> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <1> details:X<270.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<270> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <2> details:X<540.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<540> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <3> details:X<810.0>Y<802.0> || W<270>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<810> || MinW<216>
```

Unfortunately the minimum width of the button was not used to resolve(solve) the `GirdLayout` Constraints and  still shows the same error as the width being used was still `231dp` instead of `216dp`

```
D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=231, x2-x1>=231, x3-x2>=231, x4-x3>=231, x5-x4>=231, x5-x0<=1080 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x5-x0<=1080.
```

.
 4. Here is the state of affairs after everything goes haywire:

```
D/CommandCenter: Btn <0> details:X<0.0>Y<802.0> || W<2391>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<0> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <1> details:X<2391.0>Y<802.0> || W<2391>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<2391> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <2> details:X<4782.0>Y<802.0> || W<2391>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<4782> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <3> details:X<7173.0>Y<802.0> || W<2391>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<7173> || MinW<216>
D/CommandCenter: Btn <4> details:X<9564.0>Y<802.0> || W<2391>H<126> || PadL<31>PadR<31>PadT<25> || MarL<0>MarR<0>MarT<0> || L<9564> || MinW<216>
```